# Reduce over Javascript Object values

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to write a reduce function over Object values in Javascript? I'm looking for the analog of reducing over an array of keys:

```
Object.keys(hash).reduce(function(a, b) {

// reduce logic 

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no such native higher-order functions for objects.

You either will have to write your own, use a library (Underscore's [`_.reduce`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) does work on objects as well) or apply the Array method on the keys like you just have:

```
 Object.keys(hash).reduce(function(sum, k) {
     return sum + hash[k];
 }, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
var o = { a:1, b:2, c:3 },
    values = [];

for(var k in o) {
    values.push(o[k]);
}

var result = values.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array){
  return previousValue + currentValue;
});

console.log(result);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mkm6e/